# How to create a function that when placed as an array element would produce multiple array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to create a function `magic()` that would turn this:

```
[{a:1}, {b:2}, magic(), {e:5}]
```

into:

```
[{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}, {d:4}, {e:5}]
```

Comment: No. you CAN have that function there, and whatever it returns will become a value in that array, but functions can only return ONE thing, so it's not possible to return two values (as in your case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with that precise syntax, no. You can get *really close* in ES2015, but not exactly identical (in ES5 and earlier, you can't really get close).

In ES2015 ("ES6") and later, you can make `magic` return any *iterable* (like an array), and use it with spread notation:

```
let a = [{a:1}, {b:2}, ...magic(), {e:5}];
// Spread notation ----^^^
```

Example:

```js
// REQUIRES ES2015+ SUPPORT
function magic() {
  return [{c: 3}, {d: 4}];
}
let array = [{a:1}, {b:2}, ...magic(), {e:5}];
console.log(array);
```

In ES5 and earlier, you can make `magic` return an array and use `concat`:

```
var array = [{a:1}, {b:2}].concat(magic()).concat([{e:5}]);
```

Example:

```js
function magic() {
  return [{c: 3}, {d: 4}];
}
var array = [{a:1}, {b:2}].concat(magic()).concat([{e:5}]);
console.log(array);
```

That's not hyper-efficient as it creates and throws away a couple of temporary arrays, but 99.99% of the time, you don't care.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant, as magic doesn't know the array.
You could do something similar by passing the array and returning one in the function.

```
var arr = [{a:1}, {b:2},{e:5}];
arr = magic(arr); // do your magic
```

Another way which would work is adding magic to to Array.prototype

```
Array.prototype.magic = function(){
  // do your magic
};
var arr = [{a:1}, {b:2},{e:5}].magic();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Johannes Merz is right. You can not do it while the array is being constructed. But guess what? If you can shift the operation to the asynchronous / retarded timeline then yes you can. Lets see...

```js
function magic(){
  setTimeout(_ => {
                   var idx = arr.indexOf(arguments.callee.name);
                   arr.splice(idx,1);
                   arr.splice(idx,0,{c:3},{d:4});
                   console.log(arr);
                  },0);
  return arguments.callee.name;
}

var arr = [{a:1},{b:2},magic(),{e:5}];
```